# How to specify an array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to get the index of an array? Now I get undefined as the result of executing the "blockCreate" function, I think this is because I do not specify the index of the array, although I should get true, how to automatically indicate the index for the array?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [array1, setArray1] = useState([{ number: 1 }]);
  const [array2, setArray2] = useState([{ number: 2 }]);

  const blockCreate = () => {
    return array1.find(items => {
      const bool = array2.find(i => i.number === items.number);
      console.log(bool);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tell us more about what exactly you are trying to build. What `blockCreate()` is supposed to do, in particular?

Comment: The `array1.find` function should return `true` or `false`

Comment: I want to get true, but I get undefined

Comment: `find` returns `undefined` when there is nothing found. ```The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, undefined is returned.```

Comment: Array.find() doesn't return a boolean, instead it return the first element that matches the condition. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: I meant to say that the function passed to `array1.find` should return `true` or `false`, not that the function itself returns `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.find() doesn't return a boolean, instead it return the first element that matches the condition. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

It's quite obscure what you're trying to do, but I think what you looking for is Array.some() which return a boolean. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some